# retrieve repeateritem via jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I want to retrieve the repeateritem via jquery to my saveorder function on codebehind

This is my jquery code:

```
 function saveOrder(controlid) {
        var id = controlid.name.replace("$btnSave", "");
        console.log(id)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/mobile/Default.aspx/saveOrder',
            data: '{par:"' + id + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.d);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                console.log(response.d);
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my codebehind code:

```
 [WebMethod]
public static void saveOrder(string par)
{
    mobile_Menu m = new mobile_Menu();

    RepeaterItem row =  (RepeaterItem)m.FindControl(par);

    RadioButtonList rdblExtraSauce = (RadioButtonList)row.FindControl("rdblExtraSauce");
    CheckBoxList chkExtras = (CheckBoxList)row.FindControl("chkExtras");
    CheckBoxList chklExtraDrink = (CheckBoxList)row.FindControl("chklExtraDrink");
    RadioButtonList rdblExtraOption = (RadioButtonList)row.FindControl("rdblExtraOption");
    RadioButtonList rdblSauce = (RadioButtonList)row.FindControl("rdblSauce");
    CheckBoxList chkGarnish = (CheckBoxList)row.FindControl("chkGarnish");
    List<ListItem> emptyList = new List<ListItem>();
    HiddenField hfProductId = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfProductId");
    string rdlPriceId = ((RadioButtonList)row.FindControl("rdblSize")).SelectedValue.Split(',')[0];
    HiddenField hfMainProductId = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfMainProductId");


    //Get previous values
    if (m.Session["Cart"] != null)
    {
        m.values = (List<Order>)m.Session["Cart"];
    }

    if (chklExtraDrink.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in chklExtraDrink.Items)
            if (item.Selected) m.values.Add(new Order(item.Value.Split(',')[0], item.Value.Split(',')[1], emptyList, 1));
    }

    if (rdblExtraSauce.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        if (rdblExtraSauce.SelectedValue != "Geen saus")
        {
            m.values.Add(new Order(rdblExtraSauce.SelectedValue.Split(',')[0], rdblExtraSauce.SelectedValue.Split(',')[1], emptyList, 1));
        }
    }


    switch (Convert.ToInt32(hfMainProductId.Value))
    {
        case 16:
            m.values.Add(new Order(hfProductId.Value, rdlPriceId, m.addMultiChoice(chkGarnish), 1));
            break;
        case 17:
            //values.Add(new Order(hfProductId.Value, rdlPrice, rdblSauce.SelectedItem, addMultiChoice(chkExtras), 1)); ;
            m.values.Add(new Order(hfProductId.Value, rdlPriceId, rdblSauce.SelectedItem, m.addMultiChoice(chkExtras), 1, rdblExtraOption.SelectedItem));
            break;
        case 19:
            m.values.Add(new Order(hfProductId.Value, rdlPriceId, rdblSauce.SelectedItem, m.addMultiChoice(chkExtras), 1));
            break;
        case 20:
            m.values.Add(new Order(hfProductId.Value, rdlPriceId, rdblSauce.SelectedItem, m.addMultiChoice(chkExtras), 1)); ;
            break;
        case 21:
            m.values.Add(new Order(hfProductId.Value, rdlPriceId, rdblSauce.SelectedItem, 1));
            break;
        case 22:
            m.values.Add(new Order(hfProductId.Value, rdlPriceId, rdblSauce.SelectedItem, m.addMultiChoice(chkExtras), 1));
            break;
        default:
            m.values.Add(new Order(hfProductId.Value, rdlPriceId, m.addMultiChoice(chkGarnish), 1));
            break;
    }


    //Save updated list
    m.Session["Cart"] = m.values;

    if (m.Session["Cart"] != null)
    {
        m.btnOrder.Text = "Winkelmandje (€ " + Global.CalcTotPrice(m.values) + ")";

    }

}
```

I am not sure if I am doing it the right way, I am also new with jquery.
With this code I am getting an NullReferenceException. The uniqueID of the repeaterItem is passed succesfully via the parameter but the conversion to RepeaterItem fails.

more info: I have a nested Repeater (in total 2), where I want the RepeaterItem of the second Repeater

Comment: public static void saveOrder(string par) you dont return anything your method return type is null there for ajax give null refrence excpion

Comment: not sure it has to do with the return value. The code fails at row variable and is null.

Comment: body ajax calls method and method has to return a value when you are not returning anything "I want to retrieve the repeateritem via jquery to my saveorder function on codebehind " if you want to retrive the list pass the list to ajax . you are logging the data                 console.log(data.d); but there is no freaking data therefore null refrence excpetion either romove data from success function or pass some thing to ajax

Comment: ok if you want to pass the parameter to controller you can do it via query string '{par:"' + id + '"}', this is not needed try '/mobile/Default.aspx/saveOrder?par'+id,

Comment: I am able to get my parameter in my c# code. Maybe my writing was not clear. I want to get the repeaterItem id to my c# code to be able to retrieve all the controls inside it. The parameter par has the repeateritem uniqueid but it fails at      RepeaterItem row =  (RepeaterItem)m.FindControl(par);

Comment: (RepeaterItem)m.FindControl(par); ok ok do you try to cast the findcontrol return value to repeaterItem here? cause probably does not work in this manner you can create new instance of reapaterItem and new instance of whateverfindcontroll is returning var temp = m.FindControl(par); then do this RepeaterItem temp2 = new ReapeaterItem(){ 
filed1 = temp.field1,field2=temp.field2 }; I mean populate repeaterItem manually or use automapper nuget

Comment: when you want to cast an instance to another do what everyone is doing use automapper

Comment: could you give me an example ? I never used automapper

Comment: https://automapper.org/

Comment: in the link is the latest example of automapper

Comment: but personally i hate automapper latest version you can so i download the this package Install-Package DXSdata.AutoMapper -Version 9.0.4 with that nuget command in nuget console

Comment: then i do this var mydesiredInstance =  Mapper.Map<yourDestinationClass>(yourStartInstance);

Comment: and ofcurse i import this namespace

Comment: using AutoMapper.DXSdata;

Comment: is your problem resolved